# Reading in data into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas

When I read in a file (whether it'd be in .csv or .txt format) I tend to use the pandas.read_csv() method to read them. I was wondering if there is any difference with using this method and using with open(file). And if so, is there any advantages using one over another?

Any insights on this will be greatful. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going use `pandas` methods, then you need to read it in as a pandas dataframe.

Otherwise, you can read in data with `open(file)` if you are not using pandas methods.

Advantages to doing this would be case specific, but for example one advantage could be that you don't need to use an additional library. For example, if you were to later automate a python script by building an executable that runs daily, you could avoid using `pandas` and build an `executable` file that is much smaller, since the pandas library uses a lot of space for building executables.

Answer (score 0):

- The advantage of using **pandas**, is that you have to write minimal
  code, but also you probably load alot of stuff that you dont need.
- The advantage of using `open()` is that you have more control, and
  you program is gonna be significantly more minimalistic